# Button dissapear when my addon was used 1 time

Tags: python

Sorry for my bad english

I have recently programmed my first addon in blender, when I install the addon for the first time and activate it it works perfectly, but when I restart blender the button that starts the addon stops working, I have been trying to fix this problem for more than a month, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, thanks for reading

````
    "name": "EEVEE Procedural Sky",
    "author": "SoyKhaler",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (3, 1, 0),
    "location": "Render",
    "description": "Generate a Procedural Sky on EEVEE",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Add Mesh",
}

import bpy
import mathutils

#funciones

def main(context):
    sky_texture = bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeTexSky")
    bg = bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree.nodes["Background"]
    bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree.links.new(bg.inputs["Color"], sky_texture.outputs["Color"])
    sky_texture.sky_type = 'HOSEK_WILKIE' # or 'PREETHAM'
    sky_texture.turbidity = 8.0
    sky_texture.ground_albedo = 0.345
    sky_texture.sun_direction = mathutils.Vector((0.260274, 0.938356, 0.227476))  # add `import mathutils` at the beginning of the script
    bpy.data.worlds["World"].node_tree.nodes["Background"].inputs[1].default_value = 2.7





    for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
        for area in window.screen.areas: # iterate through areas in current screen
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                for space in area.spaces: # iterate through spaces in current VIEW_3D area
                        space.shading.type = 'RENDERED'

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Generate Procedural Sky"

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname, text=SimpleOperator.bl_label)

# Register and add to the "object" menu (required to also use F3 search "Simple Object Operator" for quick access)
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    #bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()

#interfaz grafica 


class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "EEVEE Procedural Sky Generator"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene

       
       
        # Big render button
        layout.label(text="Create Procedural Sky: ")
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 4.0
        row.operator("object.simple_operator")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()```
````

Comment: Is everything you posted in the same exact script or are they in separate files?

Comment: all in the same exact script, i was following a tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your script like this:

```
import bpy

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
# the operator code 
...

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
# the panel code
...
def menu_func():
# etc.
...

# then at the end:

classes = [
    SimpleOperator,
    LayoutDemoPanel
]

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

the `if __name__ == "__main__"` part is basically a way of telling Python "I want to run this script on it's own, not run it as an import in another script". So there should always be only one time you use that in a script. You can register multiple classes by putting them all into a list and then looping through that and registering them that way.